# How to conditionally send an async request as a pre-request in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, request

I have a situation that, if a condition holds, then I will

- send requestOne,
- do some stuff with success response,
- then I will send requestTwo.

On the other hand, if the condition is false, I will

- just send requestTwo.

**Is there a best practice or better / beautiful way of doing this?**

The requests are **async**, and here is a pseudocode:

```
if (condition) {
    sendRequestOne().then(function (response) {
        // do some stuff
    }).then(function () {
        sendRequestTwo();
    });
} else {
    sendRequestTwo();
}
```

---

Comment: There are ways to "chain" this differently so that `sendRequestTwo` doesn't have to be repeated, but I don't think it would make things more readable. However, you could just write `then(sendRequestTwo)`.

Comment: can you use `async` `await`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [ternary `?` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), you could branch between `sendRequestOne()` and [`Promise.resolve()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve).

```
(condition ? sendRequestOne() : Promise.resolve()).then(sendRequestTwo)
```

#### Demo

```js
const sleep = ms =>
  new Promise(resolve => { setTimeout(resolve, ms, ms) })

const labeled = label => async () => {
  console.log(label)
  console.log(`slept ${await sleep(1000) / 1000}s`)
}

const sendRequestOne = labeled('one')
const sendRequestTwo = labeled('two')

const demo = condition =>
  (condition ? sendRequestOne() : Promise.resolve()).then(sendRequestTwo)

;(async () => {
  console.log('condition: false')
  await demo(false)
  console.log('done')
  await sleep(2000)
  console.log('condition: true')
  await demo(true)
  console.log('done')
})()
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function call1(str , cb){ console.log(str); cb();}
function call2(str , cb){ console.log(str); cb();}
let flag= true;

if(flag){
  call1('call1',function(){
    call2('call2',function(){
    console.log('done')
   })
 })
}else{
 call2('call2',function(){
    console.log('done')
 })
}
```

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/zLmy6pqk/2/)

Comment: These are callbacks, not promises.